# Custom Jackson Serializer for Wrapper Object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the provider interface

```
interface IProvider<T> {
    T locate();
}
```

and a class containing a field of type IProvider (can be another type for other fields).

```
class MyObject {
    MyLocator<String> field;
}
```

I need to serialize instances of MyObject to JSON using Jackson 1.7. The output must be the same as if MyObject.field had been a String (i.e. no reference to ILocator).

I can't figure out how to build the custom serializer required to achieve this. Here is the structure I am trying to use for this task:

```
class MyLocatorSerializer extends SerializerBase<MyLocator<?>> {
    public MyLocatorSerializer() {
        super(MyLocator.class, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(MyLocator<?> a_value, JsonGenerator a_jgen,
            SerializerProvider a_provider) throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {
        // Insert code here to serialize a_value.locate(), whatever its type
    }

    @Override
    public JsonNode getSchema(SerializerProvider a_provider, Type a_typeHint)
            throws JsonMappingException {
        // What should I return here? I can't find documentation regarding the different schema types...
    }
}
```

The custom serializer would be registered using

```
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("MyModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null));
module.addSerializer(new MyLocatorSerializer());
objectMapper.registerModule(module);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another answer using mix-in annotations following the comment from Staxman.

```
static class JacksonCustomModule extends SimpleModule {
    public JacksonCustomModule() {
        super("JacksonCustomModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null));
    }

    @Override
    public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
        context.setMixInAnnotations(IProvider.class, IProviderMixIn.class);
        super.setupModule(context);
    }

    interface IProviderMixIn<T> {
        @JsonValue
        T locate();
    }
}
```

Activate the module with:

```
objectMapper.registerModule(new JacksonCustomModule());
```

Answer (score 2):

Apologies if I misunderstand the question, but would this be as simple as just using `@JsonValue` on 'Locate' method, instead of writing a custom serializer?
What `@JsonValue` does is take value of a property as is, and use it instead of creating a JSON Object: often this is used for serializing a POJO as a simple String or number, like so:

```
public class StringWrapper {
   @JsonValue public String value;
}
```

so that for class like:

```
public class POJO {
   public StringWrapper wrapped;
}
```

we would get serialization like:

```
{
  "wrapper" : "string value of 'value'"
}
```

instead of what would otherwise be seen:

```
{
   "wrapper" : {
      "value" : "... string value ... "
   }
}
```

Annotation can be used for any types of values obviously.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The end result you achieve is exactly what I seek. However, in my case, following your example, the class StringWrapper is part of a 3rd party library so it would be impractical to annotate it with @JsonValue.

Comment: As usual, the mix-in annotations [wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations] are the way to use these with 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Following StaxMan's answer, I inspected the workings of `@JsonValue` and got the following serializer:

```
// Based on JsonValueSerializer
private static class ProviderSerializer extends SerializerBase<IProvider<?>> {

    public ProviderSerializer() {
        super(IProvider.class, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(IProvider<?> value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {
        Object object = value.locate();

        // and if we got null, can also just write it directly
        if (object == null) {
            provider.defaultSerializeNull(jgen);
            return;
        }

        Class<?> c = object.getClass();
        JsonSerializer<Object> ser = provider.findTypedValueSerializer(c, true, null);
        // note: now we have bundled type serializer, so should NOT call with typed version
        ser.serialize(object, jgen, provider);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonNode getSchema(SerializerProvider provider, Type typeHint)
            throws JsonMappingException {
        // is this right??
        return JsonSchema.getDefaultSchemaNode();
    }
}
```

After some tests, this does what I need. However, I don't fully really understand the purpose of the `getSchema` method, so maybe I'm doing something wrong...