# Custom Jackson serialization while using @JsonFilter

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a need similar to this question: [Custom Jackson Serializer for Wrapper Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457794/custom-jackson-serializer-for-wrapper-object), but when using @JsonFilter.

I have an object structure like this:

```
@JsonFilter("orderFilter")
class Order {
    Address address;
    /* other undesired fields below */
}

@JsonFilter("addressFilter")
class Address {
    User user;
    /* other undesired fields below */
}

class User {
    Integer userId;
    /* other undesired fields below */
}
```

(I know this model doesn't make logical sense, its just for illustrating the problem)

I am using the @JsonFilter system to select specific fields at each level to include, both for security purposes and for scoping my api in a logical way. This is working fine, including a custom class that implements `PropertyFilter`.

I need serialize User as just the userId property, but cannot use annotations on the User class, since in other situations I will need to serialize the entire class.

For example, I would like to have the following output:

```
{ "address" : { "userId" : 1234 }}
```

My `PropertyFilter` implementation has a method like this:

```
    @Override
    public void serializeAsField(Object pojo, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider prov, PropertyWriter writer)
            throws Exception {
        if (include(writer)) {
            writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, prov);
        }
    }
```

and I know I can identify the user object with `writer.getName().equals("user")`, but what do I do next to control the output at this point?

**Bonus question**

Imagine `Address` had another property `List<Notes> notes`. How could I extend this solution to filter the list so that a filtered list of notes is included in the JSON output? In other words, some notes are for all users, but some are only for administrators. When a regular user is executing this call, I want to filter out admin notes.

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like this:

```
 public void serializeAsField(Address address, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider prov, PropertyWriter writer) throws Exception {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
            jgen.writeObjectFieldStart("address");
                jgen.writeNumberField("userId", address.getUser().getUserId());
            jgen.writeEndObject();
        jgen.writeEndObject();
 }
```

**And as for your bonus question**.. When you're manually marshalling to json like this - you can just check to see the type of User and marshall which notes you want.